# Как правильно верстать макет для recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview

сделал такой макет. проблема в том, что если задать слишком большой текст, то он просто не поместиться в item. может вы знаете как делать расширяемые items? или это не красиво и не правильно будет?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item"
    android:id="@+id/layout_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_num"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="afeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefaessssssssfesaaaaaaafsefaessssssssssssssssssssefaaaaaaaaa"
            android:id="@+id/street"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="11/22/11"
            android:textColor="#fcba03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/item_date"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: у вас внутри есть LinearLayout у которого фиксированная высота, сделайте ее wrap_content и должно все нормально быть

Comment: @Andrew было wrap, но тогда последний виджет не попадает в layout.